# pentaho report: how to add 'go back' button?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I have one report that shows a list of clients, including their ids.

I linked this report to another one, so when I click on an id, the second report is showing with the details of this client.

When I'm on the second report, I want to go back to the first report.

So I need to create a button on the second report.

I guess I need the javascript function  `window.history.back();` but how to implement it ?

I made a new message field, the prob is where to put this js function.
There's absolutely no information online.

If someone has done it, I would love to get some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is to code a "Home" button instead, or "Overview", or whatever name you want to give your 1st report, and have the button linked to the explicit URL of the 1st report.

Comment: I thought of this , but from multiples reports, I get to the second report explained. Which means there is more than one URL to link to second one. That's why I want to use window.history.back() function.

Comment: you can pass the referrer url as a report parameter, so you can go back to it when you press the button.